# Наложение шума на изображение методами ООП

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-7.3

Столкнулся с трудностями, пока пытался создать фильтр для наложения шума на изображение.

```
namespace PhotoEnhancer
{
    public class NoiseFilter : PixelFilter<NoiseParameters>
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Интенсивность шума";
        }

        public override Pixel ProcessPixel(Pixel originalPixel,
            NoiseParameters parameters)
        {
            var red = originalPixel.R;
            var green = originalPixel.G;
            var blue = originalPixel.B;
            var rnd = new Random();
            
            for (var i = 0; i < 340; i++)
            {
                var r = (rnd.NextDouble());
                red = (parameters.Intensity * r + (1 - parameters.Intensity) * originalPixel.R);
                var r2 = (rnd.NextDouble());
                green = (parameters.Intensity * r2 + (1 - parameters.Intensity) * originalPixel.G);
                var r3 = (rnd.NextDouble());
                blue = (parameters.Intensity * r3 + (1 - parameters.Intensity) * originalPixel.B);
            }
            return new Pixel(red, green, blue);
        }
    }
}
```

Сверху код фильтра, он принимает параметры из соответствующего класса(снизу).

```
namespace PhotoEnhancer
{
    public class NoiseParameters : IParameters
    {
        public double Intensity { get; set; }

        public ParameterInfo[] GetDescription()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new ParameterInfo() {
                    Name = "Интенсивность",
                    MinValue = 0,
                    MaxValue = 1,
                    DefaultValue = 0,
                    Increment = 0.01
                    }
            };
        }

        public void SetValues(double[] values)
        {
            Intensity = values[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Собственно, чтобы наложить шум на изображение "правильно", мне надо получить ширину и высоту изображения, но я не понимаю, как их вытащить из ещё одного модуля, в котором они вытаскиваются через { get;}. Естественно, что мне нужны именно ширина и высота оттуда, но сколько я не ломал голову, не получается придумать способа их оттуда вытащить. В коде создал обычный цикл, чтобы проверить, как работает алгебра, шум накладывается, шум цветной, но моя задача сделать шум на каждый пиксель в изображении, а не просто полоски цветные на картинке.

Код загрузки

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                buttonApply.Visible = true;
                comboBoxFilters.Visible = true;

                if (comboBoxFilters.SelectedIndex == -1)
                    comboBoxFilters.SelectedIndex = 0;

                LoadPicture((Bitmap)Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName));
            }
        }
```

Код обработки изображения.

```
 public static Bitmap Photo2Bitmap(Photo photo)
        {
            var result = new Bitmap(photo.Width, photo.Height);
            
            for(var x = 0; x < photo.Width; x++)
                for(var y = 0; y < photo.Height; y++)
                {
                    result.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(
                        (int)(photo[x, y].R * 255),
                        (int)(photo[x, y].G * 255),
                        (int)(photo[x, y].B * 255)
                        ));
                }

            return result;
        }
```

PixelFilter<>

```
public abstract class PixelFilter<TParameters> : ParametrizedFilter<TParameters>
        where TParameters : IParameters, new()
    {
        public override Photo Process(Photo original, TParameters parameters)
        {
            var newPhoto = new Photo(original.Width, original.Height);

            for (int x = 0; x < original.Width; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < original.Height; y++)
                    newPhoto[x, y] = ProcessPixel(original[x, y],
                            parameters);

            return newPhoto;
        }

        public abstract Pixel ProcessPixel(Pixel originalPixel,
            TParameters parameters);
    }
```

Класс Photo.

```
public class Photo
    {
        public int Width
        {
            get { return data.GetLength(0); }
        }

        public int Height
        {
            get { return data.GetLength(1); }
        }

        private Pixel[,] data;

        public Photo(int width, int height)
        {
            data = new Pixel[
                CheckSize(width, "ширина"),
                CheckSize(height, "высота")
                ];

        }

        public Pixel this[int x, int y]
        {
            get { return data[x, y]; }
            set { data[x, y] = value; }
        }

        private int CheckSize(int val, string name)
        {
            if (val <= 0)
                throw new Exception($"Неверная {name} {val}. Размер должен быть положительный");

            return val;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Что такое "картинка", `Bitmap`? Покажите код, где вы загружаете изображение и обрабатываете. Еще попробую угадать - оно очень медленно работает, более секунды. Кстати, почему 340? 340 раз меняете цвет одного и того же пикселя?

Comment: Добавьте код загрузки в вопрос, и код метода `LoadPicture` и код, вызывающий ваш фильтр. Пока непонятно примерно ничего.

Comment: Что такое `Photo`?

Comment: @aepot Добавил всё, что причастно к моей проблеме, вызов фильтра происходит после выбора соответствующего пункта ToolStrip и подтверждения изменения параметров по нажатию кнопки. Проект WInForms, так что этот код почти весь сгенерирован автоматически(код кнопки/ивента).

Comment: @aepot Я добавил код класса Photo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Быстрое преобразование `Bitmap`

Работать с `Bitmap` через GetPixel/SetPixel - это просто супермедленно. Вот например фильтр - как сделать картинку черно-белой (просто у меня был готовый пример):

```cs
public static Bitmap ToGrayScale(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    int stride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
    int length = stride * bmp.Height;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length]; // содержимое буфера будет [B G R B G R B G R...]
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, buffer, 0, bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height); // stride может быть отрицательным (строчки снизу вверх), именно здесь это важно
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    for (int row = 0; row < bmp.Height; row++)
    {
        int rowOffset = stride * row;
        for (int col = 0; col < bmp.Width; col++)
        {
            int offset = rowOffset + col * 3; // 24bpp = 3 bytes per pixel
            byte brightness = (byte)(buffer[offset] * 0.114f + buffer[offset + 1] * 0.587f + buffer[offset + 2] * 0.299f); // формула получения яркости 0.114 * B + 0.587f * G + 0.299f * R
            buffer[offset] = brightness;
            buffer[offset + 1] = brightness;
            buffer[offset + 2] = brightness;
        }
    }
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData resultData = result.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, length);
    result.UnlockBits(resultData);
    return result;
}
```

Работа через GetPixel/SetPixel для картинки 2560x1440 заняла бы 2,5 секунды, данный код отработает за ~60мс.

Как прочитать, обработать и записать картинку

```cs
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("image.jpg");
Bitmap result = ToGrayscale(bmp);
result.Save("out.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

---

#### Генератор шума

Давайте теперь пошумим. Чтобы не прикручивать ваши структуры, напишу очень простой фильтр, добавляющий шум по яркости со смещением [-20..+20]

```cs
public static Bitmap SetNoise(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    int stride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
    int length = stride * bmp.Height;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length]; // содержимое буфера будет [B G R B G R B G R...]
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, buffer, 0, bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height); // stride может быть отрицательным (строчки снизу вверх), именно здесь это важно
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    for (int row = 0; row < bmp.Height; row++)
    {
        int rowOffset = stride * row;
        for (int col = 0; col < bmp.Width; col++)
        {
            int offset = rowOffset + col * 3;

            int b = buffer[offset] + rnd.Next(-20, 21); // правая граница не включена в рандом
            int g = buffer[offset + 1] + rnd.Next(-20, 21);
            int r = buffer[offset + 2] + rnd.Next(-20, 21);

            buffer[offset] = ToByteSaturate(b);
            buffer[offset + 1] = ToByteSaturate(g);
            buffer[offset + 2] = ToByteSaturate(r);
        }
    }
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData resultData = result.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, length);
    result.UnlockBits(resultData);
    return result;
}

private static byte ToByteSaturate(int number)
{
    if (number > byte.MaxValue)
        return byte.MaxValue;
    if (number < byte.MinValue)
        return byte.MinValue;
    return (byte)number;
}
```

Было

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, этот метод работы с картинками в 50-100 раз быстрее, чем через `GetPixel`/`SetPixel`, пользуйтесь.

---

#### ООП

Теперь давайте переложу это все на ООП, чтобы было прикольнее всем этим пользоваться. Сразу оговорюсь, что здесь нет обработки исключений и нет оптимизаций по производительности, но работает весьма быстро.

Класс картинки, отвечает за хранение данных о картинке, а так же чтение ее из `Bitmap` и преобразование ее обратно.

```cs
public class Photo
{
    public byte[] Buffer { get; }
    public int Stride { get; }
    public int Width { get; }
    public int Height { get; }

    public Photo(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        Width = bmp.Width;
        Height = bmp.Height;
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        Stride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
        Buffer = new byte[Stride * bmp.Height];
        Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, Buffer, 0, bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    }

    public Bitmap ToBitmap()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        Marshal.Copy(Buffer, 0, bmpData.Scan0, Buffer.Length);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Далее, реализация фильтра

```cs
public struct Pixel
{
    public Pixel(byte b, byte g, byte r)
    {
        B = b;
        G = g;
        R = r;
    }

    public byte B { get; }
    public byte G { get; }
    public byte R { get; }
}

public interface IFilter
{
    public void Apply(Photo photo);
}

public abstract class Filter : IFilter
{
    public virtual void Apply(Photo photo)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < photo.Height; row++)
        {
            int rowOffset = photo.Stride * row;
            for (int col = 0; col < photo.Width; col++)
            {
                int offset = rowOffset + col * 3; // 24bpp = 3 bytes per pixel
                Pixel pixel = ConvertPixel(new Pixel(photo.Buffer[offset], photo.Buffer[offset + 1], photo.Buffer[offset + 2]));
                photo.Buffer[offset] = pixel.B;
                photo.Buffer[offset + 1] = pixel.G;
                photo.Buffer[offset + 2] = pixel.R;
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract Pixel ConvertPixel(Pixel pixel);
}
```

Здесь все просто, фильтр просто применяет цветокоррекцию к каждому пикселю, причем сама цветокоррекция задается в классе, наследующем эту абстракцию.

Давайте обесцветим картинку

```cs
public class GrayScaleFilter : Filter
{
    protected override Pixel ConvertPixel(Pixel pixel)
    {
        byte brightness = (byte)(pixel.B * 0.114f + pixel.G * 0.587f + pixel.R * 0.299f);
        return new Pixel(brightness, brightness, brightness);
    }
}
```

Теперь воспользуюсь этим фильтром

```cs
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("image.jpg");
Photo photo = new Photo(bmp);
GrayScaleFilter grayFilter = new GrayScaleFilter();
grayFilter.Apply(photo);
Bitmap res = photo.ToBitmap();
res.Save("_gray.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или вот самый простой фильтр-негатив

```cs
public class NegativeFilter : Filter
{
    protected override Pixel ConvertPixel(Pixel pixel)
    {
        return new Pixel((byte)(255 - pixel.B), (byte)(255 - pixel.G), (byte)(255 - pixel.R));
    }
}
```

```cs
NegativeFilter negativeFilter = new NegativeFilter();
negativeFilter.Apply(photo);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь параметризованный фильтр, здесь я создам дженерик абстракцию, которая будет отвечать за прием и хранение параметров. То что я увидел у вас в вопросе - это излишества. Старайтесь понимать, за что у вас отвечат тот или иной класс, и старайтесь сделать так, чтобы он отвечал только за что-то одно (принцип SRP из SOLID).

```cs
public abstract class ParametrizedFilter<T> : Filter 
    where T : struct
{
    public T Parameters { get; }

    public ParametrizedFilter(T parameters)
    {
        Parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

А вы ждали что-то покруче? :)

Теперь создам параметры для фильтра шума, и собственно сам фильтр.

```cs
public struct NoiseParameters
{
    public NoiseParameters(int intensity, byte minValue = byte.MinValue, byte maxValue = byte.MaxValue)
    {
        Intensity = intensity;
        MinValue = minValue;
        MaxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public int Intensity { get; }
    public byte MinValue { get; }
    public byte MaxValue { get; }
}


public class NoiseFilter : ParametrizedFilter<NoiseParameters>
{
    private readonly Random _rnd;

    public NoiseFilter(NoiseParameters parameters) : base(parameters)
    {
        _rnd = new Random();
    }

    protected override Pixel ConvertPixel(Pixel pixel)
    {
        int b = pixel.B + _rnd.Next(-Parameters.Intensity, Parameters.Intensity); 
        int g = pixel.G + _rnd.Next(-Parameters.Intensity, Parameters.Intensity);
        int r = pixel.R + _rnd.Next(-Parameters.Intensity, Parameters.Intensity);

        return new Pixel(ToByteSaturate(b), ToByteSaturate(g), ToByteSaturate(r));
    }

    private byte ToByteSaturate(int number)
    {
        if (number > Parameters.MaxValue)
            return Parameters.MaxValue;
        if (number < Parameters.MinValue)
            return Parameters.MinValue;
        return (byte)number;
    }
}
```

Вот и всего делов.

```cs
NoiseFilter noiseFilter = new NoiseFilter(new NoiseParameters(50));
noiseFilter.Apply(photo);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и напоследок, почему же все-таки метод `Apply` имеет модификатор `virtual`. А чтобы можно было переопределить его для реализации более сложного фильтра, чем попиксельный.

Вот пример сложного фильтра - [оператор Собеля](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F).

```cs
public class SobelOperator : GrayScaleFilter
{
    public override void Apply(Photo photo)
    {
        base.Apply(photo); // обесцвечивание

        const int bpp = 3;
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[photo.Buffer.Length];
        for (int row = 1; row < photo.Height - 1; row++)
        {
            int rowOffset = photo.Stride * row;
            for (int col = 1; col < photo.Width - 1; col++)
            {
                int offset = rowOffset + col * bpp; // 24bpp = 3 bytes per pixel
                int gx = -photo.Buffer[offset - bpp - photo.Stride] + photo.Buffer[offset + bpp - photo.Stride] - 2 * photo.Buffer[offset - bpp] +
                        2 * photo.Buffer[offset + bpp] - photo.Buffer[offset - bpp + photo.Stride] + photo.Buffer[offset + bpp + photo.Stride];

                int gy = photo.Buffer[offset - bpp - photo.Stride] + 2 * photo.Buffer[offset - photo.Stride] + photo.Buffer[offset + bpp - photo.Stride] -
                    photo.Buffer[offset - bpp + photo.Stride] - 2 * photo.Buffer[offset + photo.Stride] - photo.Buffer[offset + bpp + photo.Stride];

                int g = (int)MathF.Sqrt(gx * gx + gy * gy);
                if (g > byte.MaxValue)
                    g = byte.MaxValue;
                byte gb = (byte)g;

                tempBuffer[offset] = gb;
                tempBuffer[offset + 1] = gb;
                tempBuffer[offset + 2] = gb;
            }
        }
        Array.Copy(tempBuffer, photo.Buffer, tempBuffer.Length);
    }
}
```

```cs
SobelOperator sobelFilter = new SobelOperator();
sobelFilter.Apply(photo);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за метод! Я бы обязательно воспользовался им, если бы мог. Преподаватель дал чёткие задачи, я должен использовать все созданные классы и методы, да, это медленно, я с вами абсолютно согласен, даже на моей машине 1000 ротаций цикла занимала 9-15 секунд, но я либо должен улучшить существующий метод, не изменяя его до неузнаваемости, либо мириться с медленной работой. В общем, шум нужно сделать именно через двойной цикл и обработать каждый пиксель на изображении не постарев в процессе.

Comment: И да, у меня тоже есть фильтр ч\б. `public override Pixel ProcessPixel(Pixel originalPixel,
            EmptyParameters parameters)
        {
            var chanel = 0.3 * originalPixel.R +
                        0.6 * originalPixel.G +
                        0.1 * originalPixel.B;

            return new Pixel(chanel, chanel, chanel);
        }` Вот так выглядит

Comment: @КириллПачин вам никто не мешает использовать ваше наследование и дженерики, вы можете внутри цикла обработки изображения творить что угодно. Я вам показал 2 разных фильтра, доработайте под свою архитектуру, передавайте в метод экземпляр вашего фильтра, тогда условия, поставленные преподавателем будут соблюдены. И 15 секунд для 1000 итераций, это явно не для 2560x1440 картинки.

Comment: Тогда, я попробую, очень надеюсь, что это не займёт вечность.

Comment: И всё-таки, я не получил ответ на главный вопрос, как мне выудить информацию об изображении в свой фильтр? Мне всё ещё нужны ширина и высота.

Comment: @КириллПачин другими словами, фильтр - это не обязательно обработка одного пикселя, фильтр - это может быть матрица (ядро), как например в [операторе Собеля](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F), то есть фильтр должен иметь доступ не только к текущему пикселю, а еще и к соседним, иначе вашему приложению будет некуда дальше развиваться.

Comment: @КириллПачин `как мне выудить информацию об изображении в свой фильтр` - посмотрите еще раз внимательно на методы, которые я вам показал, там есть всё - и ширина, и высота.

Comment: И всё же, как бы я не изучал ваш метод, у меня просто отсутствует возможность использовать битмап. Мне необходимо использовать методы абстрактного класса `PixelFilter`, было бы хорошо, если бы в нём был прописан битмап, но нет, в нём используется класс `Photo`, в котором, в свою очередь создаётся `private Pixel[,]`, который и хранит в себе нужные мне данные, но попытка достать их оттуда обречена на провал. Логика вашего метода, тем не менее, мне кажется вполне понятной, в отличие от того, что я должен сделать.

Comment: @КириллПачин вообще показанный метод можно разбить на 3 части: 1) Преобразование `Bitmap` в буфер, 2) обработка 3) Создание нового `Bitmap` и запись в него буфера. То есть сам фильтр - это только то что посередине, он и есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @КириллПачин _у меня просто отсутствует возможность использовать битмап_ - а это тогда что `(Bitmap)Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName)`, не `Bitmap` ли?

Comment: Да, я понимаю, где находится сам фильтр и я могу его написать, это не составляет никаких проблем, ведь у меня есть заданная формула, однако, чтобы написать этот фильтр, мне нужны переменные Width и Height

Comment: Не битмап ли? Битмап, вот только просто взять из него переменные я не могу

Comment: @КириллПачин дополнил ответ.

Comment: Это, просто, даже не знаю, как вас благодарить. Теперь это практически идентично структуре данного мне кода. Крайне признателен за потраченное время и силы!

Comment: @КириллПачин Не за что. Обратите внимание на то, что у меня `Pixel` имеет конструктор B-G-R, а не R-G-B, это профдеформация, так как в `Bitmap` он именно в таком порядке следуют. Но вы можете переделать.

Comment: @КириллПачин кстати, при желании можно переопределить `Apply` и вшить туда свой алгоритм обработки изображения. С одномерным буфером работать конечно сложнее, чем с двумерным массивом пикселей, но зато быстрее. Я например в эту модель могу легко встроить тот же оператор Собеля, очень быстро. Могу показать, если интересно.

Comment: Если моих мозгов хватит, чтобы это понять, то буду рад это увидеть) Полезный опыт на дороге не валяется.

Comment: @КириллПачин готово.