# Приложение на WF для обработки изображения

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-7.3

Есть программа, выполняет функцию дешёвого фотошопа, создаётся в учебных целях. Моё задание - создать фильтр, который сужает картинку(`Bitmap`, если что), всё это в обёртке ООП.

```cs
public Point? MapPoint(Point point)
{
    point = new Point(point.X - ResultSize.Width / 2, point.Y);

    var percent = CuttedPart / 100;
    var y = (int)(point.Y);
    percent += (1 - percent) * (point.Y / (double)ResultSize.Height);
    var x = ResultSize.Width / 2 + (int)(point.X / percent);

    if (x < 0 || x > originalSize.Width - 1)
        return null;

    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Код выполняет свою задачу, однако, делает это он не правильно. [image: Пример выполнения моей программой]

Правильный вариант выглядит как-то так

[image: Правильный вариант]

Вопрос, что нужно изменить в математике, чтобы заработало так, как мне надо? Все вычисления и все переменные находятся в одном этом фрагменте, так что и проблема где-то в нём.

Вызывающий код.

```
mainForm.AddFilter(new TransformFilter<ReversePerspectiveParameters>(
    "Сужение нижней части",
    new ReversePerspectiveTransformer()));
```

Код вызывающий метод `MapPoint`

```
public override Photo Process(Photo original, TParameters parameters)
{
    var oldSize = new Size(original.Width, original.Height);
    transformer.Initialize(oldSize, parameters);

    var result = new Photo(transformer.ResultSize.Width, transformer.ResultSize.Height);

    for(var x = 0; x < result.Width; x++)
        for(var y = 0; y < result.Height; y++)
        {
            var oldPoint = transformer.MapPoint(new Point(x, y));
            if(oldPoint.HasValue)
                result[x, y] = original[oldPoint.Value.X, oldPoint.Value.Y];
        }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Это типа пересчет координат пикселя?

Comment: @aepot, я бы назвал это "сжатием" пикселей, по крайней мере так формулируется задание, но, да это изменение координат.

Comment: Двигаясь по строкам матрицы снизу-вверх, сначала определять "оффсеты" слева и справа, а потом отрисовываем n средних пикселей с пропусками. Чем выше строка, тем меньше оффесты по краям и тем реже пропускаем пиксели в середине

Comment: @SmorcIRL звучит сложно, не покажете пример?

Comment: А ResultSize у вас это что?

Comment: Размер изображения, получается через { get ; set }. Конвертируется в битмап карту.

Comment: Ответил что имел в виду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так получается. При условии что это `System.Drawing.Point`.

```cs
public Point? MapPoint(Point point)
{
    float x = point.X;
    float y = point.Y;
    float progress = 1.0f - y / ResultSize.Height;

    float lineZoom = 100.0f / (100.0f - CuttedPart + CuttedPart * progress);
    x = x * lineZoom + ResultSize.Width * (1.0f - lineZoom) / 2.0f;

    if (x < 0 || x > originalSize.Width - 1)
        return null;

    return new Point((int)x, (int)y);
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118436/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot---wf---).

Answer (score 1):

Вот как-то так можно:

```
static Bitmap Func(Bitmap orig)
{
    int w = orig.Width;
    int h = orig.Height;
    
    var res = new Bitmap(w, h);

    const double percent = 0.3;

    int skip = (int) (w * (1 - percent));

    for (int i = h - 1; i >= 0; i--, skip--)
    {
        int take = w - skip;
        double step = (double) w / take;

        for (int j = 0; j < take ; j++)
        {
            res.SetPixel(skip / 2 + j, i, orig.GetPixel((int) Clamp(j * step, 0, w - 1), i));
        }
    }

    return res;
}

static double Clamp(double val, double min, double max)
{
    return val > max ? max : val < min ? min : val;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу использовать Math.Clamp, мой visual studio не хочет работать с .net framework 5.0.

Comment: @КириллПачин Не проблема, добавил

Comment: Ещё одно, в данном методе я не могу использовать bitmap, здесь всё завязано на координатах пикселей, это уже другая форма реализации, от чистого bitmap программа отошла. Размеры, тем не менее изначально были в битмап, но позже преобразовались в класс System.Drawing.Size

Comment: [Там что-то такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567), наверное.