# Как найти координаты всех изображений на белом фоне?

Tags: c#

На белом фоне могут находится несколько черно-белых иконок. Как мне получить координаты x, y всех иконок и вернуть размер каждой? Как это можно сделать попиксельно?

Картинка совсем небольшая с 3-5 изображениями...

```
var image = new Bitmap(@"/icons.png");

int left = 0, top = 0;
int width = 0, height = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
   {
     // Тут логика
     if (image.GetPixel(x, y).R != 255)
     {

     }

   }

}

//MessageBox.Show("Координаты: " + left.ToString() + "x" + top.ToString() + " Размер картинки: " + width + "x" + height + "\r\n");



image.Dispose();
```

Comment: Когда я был молод и горяч, я делал [вот такое](https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2013/09/linqpad.html), но это самый топоррый, не очень точный и вероятно не оптимальный способ.

Comment: @tym32167 ну мне зашло, вполне себе хороший алгоритм. Автору вопроса не хватает только способа перегнать картинку в массив и обратно, чтобы не мучать ее попиксельно (потому что это ооооооочень медленно работает). Подсмотреть быстрый способ конвертировать битмап-массив-битмап можно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567).

Comment: Ну я тоже так умею) Но мне нужно попиксельно, пока думаю над логикой, как бы лучше поступить, чтобы не городить кучу лишнего кода

Comment: aepot, о, спасибо, пригодится!

Comment: Чтобы не перебирать каждый пиксель делайте первоначальную проверку например каждые 10-20 пикселей, если обнаружили край картинки, то возвращаетесь на итерацию и более точно определяете край.

Comment: Уважаемые коллеги, к сожалению, в связи с недавней регистрацией, я не могу проставить лайки, за действительно полезные комментарии, система попросту  не позволяет мне это делать. Очень прошу отнестись с пониманием, все советы и решения для меня были очень полезны) Большое спасибо!!!