# Список только отображаемых окон Windows

Tags: c#, winapi

Перебираю все окна Windows через EnumWindows, что бы сделать скриншоты всех открытых окошек приложений. Но кроме тех окон, которые я действительно вижу на экране, EnumWindows возвращает мне еще кучу ненужных невидимых окон, например:

Microsoft Text Input Application,
Microsoft Store (2штуки),
Параметры (2штуки),
Кино и ТВ (2штуки),
и т.д.

они проходят проверки IsVisible=true и IsIconic=False, имеют в качестве изображения вполне себе черный прямоугольник (получаю его через GetWindowRect) конкретных размером и именно этим мешают жить.

Как можно отличить их от обычных окошек, которые я вижу на экране? Что бы не делать с них скриншотов (они чоорные и бесполезные ))

Вот что я наваял:

```
class OpenWindowsGetter
{
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hwnd);

    delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);
        /// <summary>Returns a dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</summary>
        /// <returns>A dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</returns>
        public static IDictionary<IntPtr, string> GetOpenWindows()
        {
            IntPtr lShellWindow = GetShellWindow();
            Dictionary<IntPtr, string> lWindows = new Dictionary<IntPtr, string>();

            EnumWindows(delegate (IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
            {
                if (hWnd == lShellWindow) return true;
                if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;
                if (IsIconic(hWnd)) return true;

                int lLength = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
                if (lLength == 0) return true;

                StringBuilder lBuilder = new StringBuilder(lLength);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, lBuilder, lLength + 1);

                lWindows[hWnd] = lBuilder.ToString();
                return true;

            }, 0);

            return lWindows;
        }
}
```

Потом где нибудь обрабатываем нажатие накнопку и оптравляем список окон в комбобокс WindsCB

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindsCB.Items.Clear(); 
        IDictionary<IntPtr, string> winds = OpenWindowsGetter.GetOpenWindows();
        foreach (var item in winds) WindsCB.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

всем заранее огроменное спасибо!

Comment: Как это запустить для отладки?

Comment: импортировать из USER32.DLL методы GetShellWindow, EnumWindows, IsWindowVisible, IsIconic, GetWindowTextLength, GetWindowText : например         [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]  static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

и т.д.
я не думал, что кто то будет это отлаживать, надеялся просто знаете как отличить отображаемые окна от тех, которые есть но не отображаются на экране (типа "Microsoft Store")

Comment: Вопрос можно редактировать - кнопка "Править"

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f5912000-74b7-42b7-a070-a647fad2ffe9/black-screen-or-image-on-screen-capture-of-windows-applications?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues, кстати, а почему бы просто не проверить битмап на тот факт, что он полностью черный? Если черный - выбросить.

Comment: наверное можно и проверить на черноту, хотя тоже надо подумать - а как это сделать, но вообще должен же бы быть способ узнать, что отображается, а что нет. Иначе как то непонятно :)

Comment: спасибо за ссылку
там правда проблема в другом - скриншоты микрософтовских окон черные, тоже прикольная проблема, все фоткаются, а МС нет.

Comment: Есть окна со стилем WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP отрисовывающиеся посредством Direct Composition. И даже у перекрытых окон совсем не обязательно может быть визуальное представление.

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567) я издевался над битмапами. Я думаю, методика простая, как очень быстро чекнуть битмап на нули.

Comment: user7860670, я видимо плохо описал проблему. Поправил. Но уточню опять - я вижу на мониторе 4 окна (например), а EnumWindows выдает мне больше десятка - каких то непонятных окон, которых вовсе нет на экране и их изображение (черные прямоугольники) мне вовсе и не нужны. Только я их не могу программно отличить от "хороших" окон.  Вот, советуют глянуть саму картинку на черноту. Тоже вариант, хотя и кажется немного косвенным решением, а не прямым.

Comment: @aepot , в общем других вариантов кроме проверки на черность не нашел, так что большое вам спасибо! Особенно за быстрый код работы с битмапами.
Остался правда один вопрос, не принципиальный -  скришоты с непонятных системных окон выглядят черными, но если смотреть побитно в вашем примере ( в массив buffer ), то некоторые биты не ноль. Почему так может быть, не знаете?  Я в итоге взял среднее число Buffer.Average(x => (byte)x)  и если оно меньше 3х, то считаю окно черным. Но все таки как то странно ...

Comment: @МихаилСолодков не знаю, почему не ноль. В битмапах есть свои приколы типа выравнивания 4 байта в конце каждой строки. То есть в области паддинга может быть любой мусор. Поэтому если нужна гарантия, что все байты "рабочие", то используйте ARGB. Ну либо использовать RGB (он быстрее), но учитывать построчный паддинг, как я это делаю в коде по ссылке. Кстати `IEnumerable.Average` - медленно, обычный цикл `for` будет работать быстрее, но вы потестируйте.

Comment: @aepot, да, действительно, с PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb всё четко. Спасибо еще раз.