# Как сделать негатив изображения в OpenCV?

Tags: c#, opencv

Находил решения на C++, видимо, они устарелые, так как у меня не получилось подогнать их к версии 4 на C#.

Пробовал эксперименты вроде что-то этого:

```
Mat[] p;
Cv2.Split(src, out p);

Cv2.BitwiseNot(p[1], p[1]);

Mat m = new Mat();
Cv2.Merge(p, m);
```

Но это не то, что хотелось бы...

Пробовал еще так:

```
Mat src = new Mat(path);
src = 255 - src;
```

Но также не то, получается не негатив...

Comment: А зачем вы сдвинули код на середину страницы?

Comment: `получается не негатив`, а что получается?

Comment: А какой размерности получается src и какие там числа к примеру? А то может там 4 компоненты - RGBA (ну или BGRA или как там у CV2 - суть не важно) и четвёртую компоненту не надо трогать, или может там числа не от 0 до 255, а от 0 до 1.0 и тогда надо вычитать из 1.0, надо же смотреть на цифры, прежде чем что-то делать.

Comment: Прошу прощения, поправил код. С последним кодом на выходе получаю изображение сильно затемненное синим цветом. Мне подходит ЧБ и цветное изображение. Хочу на выходе получить результат как это делают программы. Пробовал imagemagick, отрабатывает нормально, но как это можно сделать в opencv?

Comment: Какой размерности получается src в Cv2 - спасибо, сейчас посмотрю и дам знать. UPD только, думаю, как мне это проверить ?

Comment: @JuriiM А какого типа данные в `src`? Если там `numpy.array`, то `src.shape` можно посмотреть. Ну и вообще попробовать напечатать хоть кусочек этого `src`, что там вообще.

Comment: @CrazyElf По моему там 4 компоненты - RGBA. Остальное в ближайшее время изучу для общего понимая, просто я новичок в коддинге. Но по моему меня все устроило, второй вариант переводит в негатив, то что нужно, единственное, вместо белого фона, получается синий, а так то же самое, правда, изображение в общем довольно затемнено синим цветом вместо белого фона. Но в целом, если подстроить яркости и тени, контраст, то все устраивает. Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567) я делал средствами GDI+ (System.Drawing). OpenCV к сожалению незнаю.

Comment: Не надо ничего сплитить. Сделайте просто  bitwisenot ко всей картинке.

Comment: Alex Alex, спасибо! Удалил все, оставил только BitwiseNot. Все получилось! Не пойму, как я тогда не разобрал это) После я сделал через bitmapData, с локом. Но opencv практичней. Благодарю!!! И извиняюсь за долгий ответ, уведомление на почте заметил только сегодня...