# Как наложить PNG изображения с плавным переходом?

Tags: c#, png

Сабж. 
Есть фон. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И есть картинка которою нужно разместить на фоне
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проблема с прозрачными краями.
Должно получится так (увеличил изображение что бы было понятно), это картинка с фотошопа.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня получается вот так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код которым я склеиваю изображения.

```C#
        public static Bitmap Glue(Bitmap sourse, Bitmap img) 
        {
            Bitmap result = sourse;
            for (int w = 0; w< result.Width; w++)               
            {
                for (int h = 0; h < result.Height; h++) 
                {
                    Color pixelColor = img.GetPixel(w, h);

                    if(pixelColor.R != 0 && pixelColor.G != 0 && pixelColor.B != 0 || pixelColor.A != 0 ) 
                    {    
                            result.SetPixel(w, h, pixelColor);    
                    }
                }

            }
            return result;
        }   
    }
```

Собственно как получить картинку с плавными краями? Это можно сделать просто правильно подставив пиксили или же у фотошопа и прочих редакторов края обрабатываются неким алгоритмом который все это делает?

Comment: У png картинки альфа-канал есть?

Comment: Да, у изображения которое нужно накладывать есть альфа канал, и у фона есть альфа канал равный 255 во всех пикселях. У краев изображение которое нужно накладывать значение альфа-канала снижается.

Comment: Ну и где добавление пикселя на фон? Я только вижу условие на наличие хоть какого то цвета и замещение пикселя. Нужно делать добавление цвета пикселя с поправкой на альфа-канал.

Comment: Ну я проверяю если в пиксиле какой либо цвет если есть значит вставляю его, если цвета нет то не заменяю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы перемудрили, GDI+ (`System.Drawing`) уже всё умеет, что вам нужно.

```cs
using Image back = Image.FromFile("back.png");
using Image icon = Image.FromFile("image.png");
using Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(back);
g.DrawImage(icon, Point.Empty); // наложить картинку на координатах (0, 0)
back.Save("result.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Где `back.png` - фон, `image.png` - иконка, `result.png` - готовое изображение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще никогда не используйте `GetPixel`/`SetPixel` если вам нужно обработать группу пикселей - это супермедленный метод работы с изображениями. [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567) есть другие методы быстрой работы с картинками.