# Трансформация объектов структуры Drawing.Point

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Существует некоторый кустарный "фотошоп", написан методами ООП. В этом неладном графическом редакторе существует фильтр, который делает из одной картинки 4, отражённых друг от друга.
[image: Пример работы]

Фильтр, казлось бы, выполняет всё, что от него просят, однако появилась необходимость сделать итоговое изображение в 2 раза шире и в 2 раза выше исходного. Выглядит логика фильтра следующим образом.

```
                int x = point.X;
                int y = point.Y;

                if (x < size.Width / 2)
                    x = x * 2;
                else
                    x = (size.Width - x - 1) * 2;

                if (y < size.Height / 2)
                    y = y * 2;                
                else
                    y = (size.Height - y - 1) * 2;

                return new Point(x, y);
```

Попытка в лоб удвоить значения Высоты и Ширины проваливается, т.к. каждый пиксель изображения считается и заносится в массив, который, соответственно, ругается когда значения первышают его изначальный размер. Как поступить в таком случае, если сам массив изменять нельзя.

```
public class Photo
{
    public int Width
    {
        get { return data.GetLength(0); }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return data.GetLength(1); }
    }

    private Pixel[,] data;

    public Photo(int width, int height)
    {
        data = new Pixel[
            CheckSize(width, "ширина"),
            CheckSize(height, "высота")
            ];
    }

    public Pixel this[int x, int y]
    {
        get {  return data[x, y]; }
        set { data[x, y] = value; }
    }

    private int CheckSize(int val, string name)
    {
        if (val <= 0)
            throw new Exception($"Неверная {name} {val}. Размер должен быть положительный");

        return val;
    }

}
```

Comment: При чём тут `Point`? Нужно удваивать размеры `Bitmap`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov В данном проекте работа с изображениями ведётся не через Bitmap, а через собственный конструктор. Поэтому методы битмапа не пригодны.

Comment: Bitmap - это фактически массив пикселей. Нужна картинка большего размера - нужно изменить размер массива. Всё! Меняйте (увеличивайте) свой массив.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я бы и рад, да трогать его нельзя. Разве что копировать имеющийся с новым именем, но тогда мне придётся лопатить весь проект и менять наследование.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov В вопрос добавил класс, в котором происходит создание массива, обучение странная вещь, не думаю, что в реальном опыте мне понадобится создавать подобный велосипед, но сейчас сказали сделать это чудо, я сделал и теперь не знаю, как с ним работать.

Comment: `Photo(int width, int height)` - ну вот же конструктор, принимающий размеры. Появилась необходимость создать изображение в 2 раза больше - вызываем этот конструктор с увеличенными размерами.

Comment: Связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм следующий:

1. создать новый битмап с размерами в 2 раза больше исходного изображения
2. скопировать исходное изображение в писксель 0,0
3. отзеркалить изображение и скопировать в позицию 0,%ширина исходного изображения +1%
4. // сделать идентичный процесс еще 2 раза для получения нижнего отзеркаливания
5. присвоить в изображение твоего редактора получившийся битмап