# Метод Bitmap.ToNDArray возвращает не правильный массив данных

Tags: c#, numpy

К примеру на python с метода np.asarray(Image.open("test_photo.jpg")) данные приходят в следующем виде:

```
[[[[50 46 47]
  [50 46 47]
  [50 46 47]
  ...
  [50 46 47]
  [50 46 47]
  [50 46 47]]

 [[51 47 48]
  [51 47 48]
  [51 47 48]
  ...
  [50 46 47]
  [50 46 47]
  [50 46 47]]

 [[52 48 49]
  [52 48 49]
  [52 48 49]
  ...
  [50 46 47]
  [50 46 47]
  [50 46 47]]

 ...

 [[55 53 54]
  [55 53 54]
  [55 53 54]
  ...
  [81 86 92]
  [79 86 92]
  [79 86 92]]

 [[55 53 54]
  [55 53 54]
  [55 53 54]
  ...
  [81 86 92]
  [81 85 94]
  [81 85 94]]

 [[55 53 54]
  [55 53 54]
  [55 53 54]
  ...
  [81 86 92]
  [80 84 93]
  [80 84 93]]]]
```

на C#

```
Bitmap imbit = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("test_photo.jpg"));  
NDArray ndarray = imbit.ToNDArray(flat: false, copy: true, discardAlpha: true);
```

Данные в переменной ndarray:

```
[[[[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50], 
 ... 
[48, 47, 51], 
[48, 47, 51], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50]], 
[[48, 47, 51], 
[48, 47, 51], 
[48, 47, 51], 
[48, 47, 51], 
[48, 47, 51], 
 ... 
[48, 47, 51], 
[48, 47, 51], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50]], 
[[49, 48, 52], 
[49, 48, 52], 
[49, 48, 52], 
[48, 47, 51], 
[48, 47, 51], 
 ... 
[48, 47, 51], 
[48, 47, 51], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50]], 
[[50, 49, 53], 
[50, 49, 53], 
[49, 48, 52], 
[49, 48, 52], 
[49, 48, 52], 
 ... 
[48, 47, 51], 
[48, 47, 51], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50]], 
[[50, 49, 53], 
[50, 49, 53], 
[50, 49, 53], 
[49, 48, 52], 
[49, 48, 52], 
 ... 
[48, 47, 51], 
[48, 47, 51], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50], 
[47, 46, 50]], 
 ... 
[[53, 52, 54], 
[53, 52, 54], 
[53, 52, 54], 
[53, 52, 54], 
[54, 53, 55], 
 ... 
[92, 86, 81], 
[92, 86, 79], 
[91, 85, 78], 
[91, 85, 78], 
[91, 85, 78]], 
[[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
 ... 
[93, 87, 82], 
[92, 86, 81], 
[92, 86, 81], 
[92, 86, 79], 
[92, 86, 79]], 
[[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
 ... 
[93, 87, 82], 
[92, 86, 81], 
[92, 86, 81], 
[92, 86, 79], 
[92, 86, 79]], 
[[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
 ... 
[92, 85, 82], 
[92, 86, 81], 
[92, 86, 81], 
[94, 85, 81], 
[94, 85, 81]], 
[[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
[54, 53, 55], 
 ... 
[92, 85, 82], 
[92, 86, 81], 
[92, 86, 81], 
[93, 84, 80], 
[93, 84, 80]]]]
```

Почему все наоборот ? [50, 47, 46] на [47, 46, 50]

Comment: А должно быть что?

Comment: Должно быть [50 46 47]

Comment: Ну так формат штатного битмапа - BGR в памяти, а не RGB. Видимо библиотека игнорит этот факт. Просто учтите поведение, что каналы поменяны местами, только и всего.

Comment: Либо можете свой метод трансляции написать. Правда черт его знает, что такое NDArray, выглядит как `byte[][][]`, но почему-то не он.

Comment: @aepot float[] fArr = ndarray .ToArray<float>().Select(x => (float)x).ToArray();

Comment: Есть пример метода трансляции ?

Comment: А зачем этот Select? `normalized_image_array.Cast<float>().ToArray()`. Трансляцию можно написать, но без понимания, что во что преобразовать надо, не получится. Еще надо понимать, насколько критична производительность. Судя по Linq запросам, вы вообще никуда не спешите.

Comment: Операция должна производиться 10 раз за секунду, поэтому производительность не особо важна будет

Comment: 100мс - достаточно большой промежуток времени, для FullHD картинки без напряга можно в 40мс уложиться, а если упороться в SIMD операции, то еще раз в 5 быстрее. [Вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567) можете взять за основу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187737/converting-a-bgr-bitmap-to-rgb
Вот что мне помогло

Comment: Так тоже можно, да. Смысл написания своего механизма - скорость. Вы могли бы и в финальном массиве с тем же успехом перетасовать значения.

Comment: Перетасовал, массив и все сходиться теперь for (int i = 0; i < fArr.Length; i += 3)
                        {
                            float dummy = fArr[i];
                            fArr[i] = fArr[i + 2];
                            fArr[i + 2] = dummy;
                        }