# Как заполнить массив координат Point[] для заливки?(С#| WinForms | .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Пишу аналог Paint. Нужна функция, что будет возвращать массив Point для создания Shape и последующей заливки. Код набросал вот так:

```
protected Point[] takePoints(EventArgs e) 
{
            Point points = new Point();
            //код заполняющий массив координат
           return points;
        }
```

Данные взяты из головы. Соответственно, выше нужна функция определения координат полного shape, что мы должны заполнить. Я думал её прописать с использованием цикла на изменение цвета. К примеру, береться координата 0;0 и проверяется какого она цвета. Далее идет проверка пикселей до того места, где располагается указатель пользользователя. Если по этому пути ни один пиксель не был другого цвета, соответсвенно эта координата записывается в массив и идет перебор следующей координаты.
Функция заливки выглядит так:

```
public static Color defcolor = Color.Black;

private void ColorZalivkaMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            SolidBrush myCorp = new SolidBrush(defcolor);
            g.FillPolygon(myCorp, takePoints(e));
        }
```

[image]
Тоесть, если клацнуть в серединку кляксы, то всё заполниться выбранным цветом(defcolor).
Заранее спасибо большое)
И помогите пожалуйста:)

Comment: Ничё не понял... Если взять ваш массив points, то метод `FillClosedCurve` прекрасно его заливает. Что ещё нужно?

Comment: Кажется, понял. Стандартная проблема начинающих осваивать WinForms. Не создавайте `Graphics` вызовом `CreateGraphics`. Используйте событие `Paint` и берите `Graphics` из `PaintEventArgs`.

Comment: WPF и WinForms - сильно разные технологии. Не лепите все метки подряд. Оставьте только нужные.

Comment: Э, нет! У вас в коде WinForms! Почему тогда метка WPF?

Comment: Извините за метки. Код, что возвращал координаты я оставил как пример. В цикле нужно определять эти точки и заполнять ими массив, чтобы потом можно было закрасить всё. А есть заготовленные функции для определения точек координат этой фигуры?

Comment: Вы эту фигуру как нарисовали? Вот во время рисования сохраняйте координаты точек в список `List<Point>` (сделайте его полем формы). А при заливке передайте в `FillClosedCurve`.

Comment: Алгоритм [заливки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заливка) (наводнения). В английской версии расписано больше.

Comment: Ага, спасибо, сейчас попробую чего-нибудь сделать

Comment: В WinAPI есть функция [ExtFloodFill](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-extfloodfill). В C# её вызывать через [PInvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/ExtFloodFill.html)

Comment: Значит, реализовать функцию через `List<Point>` не вышло. Первостепенная проблема заключается в том, что помимо инструмента Pen есть и другие, например : рисование эллипсов, запись текста и тп. Так же подключить `ExtFloodFill `не получалось(инвалид я, скорее всего). Остается написание функции по `Алгоритм заливки`. По этому алгоритму можно реализовать наилучший инструмент заливки(как по мне). Сейчас буду дальше пытаться сделать реализацию) Как только что-то выйдет я его добавлю ниже.

Comment: При заливке растра используйте растровые методы заливки, а не векторные. Вы пытаетесь с одной стороны брать кривую, с другой рассказываете про пиксели. Вы уж определитесь, пиксели у вас или фигура. Если первое, то математически надо вычислять, принадлежит ли точка пространству фигуры, а для этого фигура должна быть описана формулами, например кривые Безье. Если второе, то забыть про фигуры и лупить заливку по пикселям. Чтобы оно не тормозило, не используйте GetPixel/SetPixel, это мегамедленно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14897412/12888024