# C# работа с байтами изображения

Tags: c#, .net, изображения, byte, bytearray

Недавно начал изучать один древний игровой формат изображения.Из одной моей любимой игры(SpaceRangers HD).Хочу попробовать конвертировать его в современный формат png.

И так вот ближе к сути,как можно быстрее(в плане написания кода) читать файл преобразованный в массив байтов файл изображения,и можно ли подразбить скажем массив изображения на header и данные самого изображения для удобной работы?

Также я слышал что может помочь работа с буферами(так ли это)?

Comment: Вопрос не структурирован, при чем здесь буферы, проблема не ясна. Если вы о том, можно ли распарсить массив байт на структуру данных, то да, никто не запрещает. И что за древний формат, вы тоже не сказали, название игры ни о чем не говорит. Для 99% форматов есть готовые решения. Если есть цвета пикселей, можно из них собрать битмап, а битмап уже сохранить в почти любом желаемом формате. Как издеваться над битмапами, я показывал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567).

Comment: В игре свой формат gi в нём есть 5 типов первый 
0: 16 бит или 32 бит на пиксель 1 слой
1: 16 бит 1 слой
2.16 бит 3 слоя

Comment: И если что я скорее про то как можно проще парсить массив байтов который создан из картинки?

Comment: Ну битмап имеет формат байт BGRA (8-8-8-8) в самом популярном режиме работы с памятью битмапа, то есть 4 байта на пиксель. Как с ним работать - я скинул выше.

Comment: а можно работать в битмапе с 2 байтами на пиксель?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat

Comment: спасибо посмотрю

Comment: Скиньте пару таких картинок.
Гугл вообще по этому поводу не выдаёт кроме: gif, китайского знака gi, компании Gi

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ARZdkPvN4Jlu4qAyhUdJdZ0qt4LK51uF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Формат используется только в данной игре,ничто остальное не читает его.

Comment: А структуру данных этого gi формата вы знаете? Она у вас есть? Я не могу найти. Какой у файла формат заголовка? Где почитать?

Comment: Есть python скрипт где человек уже реализовал перевод из этого формата в пнг(но она поддерживает не все gi).Структура  данных примерно такова что есть заголовки в которой обозначается что это гишка,какие-то игровые start_X Start_Y и такие же finish_X finish_Y ещё 4 битовые маски(применяются только если фреймтайп имеет значение 2,если фреймтайп не 2 нули,frametype - собственно сам фреймтайп(их всего пять но игра использует два(выяснил путем изучения python скрипта),layercount - количество слоёв пока не знаю как они накладываюся,и ещё какие-то пустые байты ).

Comment: я уже нагуглил, вот вам готовый C++ https://github.com/ObKo/OpenSR/wiki/Original-Game-Resources---ru, при должном упорстве можно без особого труда переписать на шарп.

Comment: Сама картинка тоже зависит от фрейм тайпа 
16 или 32 бит и 1 слой на пиксель если тип 0
16 бит и 3 слоя если тип 2
другие типы не разбирал,но они в игре и не используются

Comment: `byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("2PirateSpecial2_00000.gi");` и вперёд :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Кстати ещё маленький наверно тупой вопрос(просто я сам то недавно в c# перешёл с python)
Можно ли указать несколько возможных типов для переменной или метода
например в питоне через модуль typing была такая реализация 

`def __init__(self, obj: BaseBuffer | bytes | bytearray = b'') -> None:`

Comment: Нет, C# строго типизирован, преобразования либо через маршаллинг, либо через конвертеры. Я думаю, в ответе есть часть того что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажу кратко, вот структура заголовков https://github.com/ObKo/OpenSR/blob/rework/include/OpenSR/libRangerQt.h на C++, в принципе она на C# переписывается только заменой `uint32_t` на `public uint`.

```cpp
struct GIFrameHeader
{
    uint32_t signature;  //!< Signature
    uint32_t version;  //!< Version of GI file
    uint32_t startX;  //!< Left corner
    uint32_t startY;  //!< Top corner
    uint32_t finishX;  //!< Right corner
    uint32_t finishY;  //!< Bottom corner
    uint32_t rBitmask;  //!< Mask of r color component
    uint32_t gBitmask;  //!< Mask of g color component
    uint32_t bBitmask;  //!< Mask of b color component
    uint32_t aBitmask;  //!< Mask of a color component
    uint32_t type;  //!< Frame type
    /*!<
     * Variants:
     *  -# 0 - One layer, 16 or 32 bit, depends on mask.
     *  -# 1 - One layer, 16 bit RGB optimized.
     *  -# 2 - Three layers:
     *   -# 16 bit RGB optimized - body
     *   -# 16 bit RGB optimized - outline
     *   -# 6 bit Alpha optimized
     *  -# 3 - Two layers:
     *   -# Indexed RGB colors
     *   -# Indexed Alpha
     *  -# 4 - One layer, indexed RGBA colors
     *  -# 5 - Delta frame of GAI animation.
     */
    uint32_t layerCount; //!< Number of layers in frame
    uint32_t unknown1;
    uint32_t unknown2;
    uint32_t unknown3;
    uint32_t unknown4;
};
```

например, если вам надо отпилить `GIFrameHeader`, а это 16 интов, то берете 16*4 байт = 64

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("2PirateSpecial2_00000.gi");
    uint[] header = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, uint>(data[..64]).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < header.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(header[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод для вашего файла

```
26983 // signature
1     // version
0     // startX
23    // startY
176   // finishX
156   // finishY
63488 // rBitmask
2016  // gBitmask
31    // bBitmask
0     // aBitmask
2     // type
3     // layerCount
0     // reserved
0     // reserved
0     // reserved
0     // reserved
```

И далее в том же духе

Полезная информация и код чтения изображения я нагуглил здесь: https://github.com/ObKo/OpenSR/wiki/Original-Game-Resources---ru

Как работать с битмапами в библиотеке `System.Drawing`, я показывал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567).

Comment: Привет спасибо за ответ ,а про что вы?

Comment: @Lorki Про -1, я даже знаю от какого модератора.

Comment: А если ты про https://prnt.sc/X5bGTwOaZ7kP,то я пытаюсь выше сделать мне пишет что мой голос публично не отображается

Comment: @Lorki нет, с этим как раз все ок. Надо вроде 25 репутации иметь, чтобы голосовать публично.

Comment: Хорошо если проблем нет,и ещё раз спасибо)