# Разложение BMP изображения на цвета

Tags: c#

Мне нужно разложить BMP изображение на три цвета RGB.Как можно получить доступ к массиву пикселей,чтобы поменять у них цвета?Желательно без WPF и WinForms.

Comment: смотрите тут (правда там кривовато, но понять можно) https://habr.com/ru/post/60085/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567

Comment: [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). Читаете заголовки Bitmap file header и DIB header, добираетесь до Pixel array, используете.

Comment: Я не смог найти этот Pixel array, я пытался разложить через класс Bitmap.А на каком смещении должен находиться этот массив?

Comment: Я же вам ссылку на готовый код дал, где работа с битмапом как с массивом, в чем на самом деле проблема? О каких заголовках вообще речь?

Comment: Вы пишете: "Желательно без WPF и WinForms", но при этом используете класс `Bitmap`. Как это понимать?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov [System.Drawng.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common)

Comment: с 10 байта в файле идет 4 байта адреса начала данных пикселей их может быть 3 байта на пискель (rgb) -24bit или 4 (rgba) -32bit, да в BMP тоже есть альфа

Comment: Я скачал nuget библиотеку common.Я имел в виду,что не хочу использовать структуру WPF или WinForms.Мне нужно было стандартное консольное приложение.Благо так можно сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использую библиотеку GDI+ [System.Drawng.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common), ту самую, которая в Winforms доступна по умолчанию.

Окей, если не получается взять и доработать [почти готовый код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567), то я доработаю

```
// синий
public static Bitmap GetBlue(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    int stride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
    int length = stride * bmp.Height;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, buffer, 0, bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    for (int row = 0; row < bmp.Height; row++)
    {
        int rowOffset = stride * row;
        for (int col = 0; col < bmp.Width; col++)
        {
            int offset = rowOffset + col * 3;
            buffer[offset + 1] = 0;
            buffer[offset + 2] = 0;
        }
    }
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData resultData = result.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, length);
    result.UnlockBits(resultData);
    return result;
}
```

```
// зеленый
public static Bitmap GetGreen(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    int stride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
    int length = stride * bmp.Height;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, buffer, 0, bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    for (int row = 0; row < bmp.Height; row++)
    {
        int rowOffset = stride * row;
        for (int col = 0; col < bmp.Width; col++)
        {
            int offset = rowOffset + col * 3;
            buffer[offset] = 0;
            buffer[offset + 2] = 0;
        }
    }
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData resultData = result.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, length);
    result.UnlockBits(resultData);
    return result;
}
```

```
// красный
public static Bitmap GetRed(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    int stride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
    int length = stride * bmp.Height;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, buffer, 0, bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    for (int row = 0; row < bmp.Height; row++)
    {
        int rowOffset = stride * row;
        for (int col = 0; col < bmp.Width; col++)
        {
            int offset = rowOffset + col * 3;
            buffer[offset] = 0;
            buffer[offset + 1] = 0;
        }
    }
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData resultData = result.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, length);
    result.UnlockBits(resultData);
    return result;
}
```

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("image.jpg");
Bitmap red = GetRed(bmp);
red.Save("red.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Bitmap green = GetGreen(bmp);
green.Save("green.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Bitmap blue = GetBlue(bmp);
blue.Save("blue.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.Просто по вашей ссылке было очень много кода,причем довольно сложного для меня.Я бы каждую строку не разобрал.Но раз уж вы написали конкретно для меня,то станет в разы проще.