# Не открывается изображение в Фотошопе после обработки C#

Tags: c#

Уменьшаю изображение через C#:

```
string originalPicPath = project.Variables["imageAddress"].Value;

int newWidth = 300;
int newHeight = 153;

System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(originalPicPath);
System.Drawing.Image resized = image.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, System.IntPtr.Zero);

image.Dispose();
File.Delete(originalPicPath);

resized.Save(originalPicPath);
resized.Dispose();
```

Сохраненную картинку мне нужно обработать в Фотошопе, но она не открывается.
Из-за чего так может происходить? Возможно C#-код с ошибками и неправильно сохраняет картинку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Изначальный формат изображения какой?

Comment: Изначальный - JPG, конечный тоже JPG. Там в коде видно, что картинка берется по одному адресу, по этому же адресу и сохраняется (переменная originalPicPath).

Comment: [Ремарку](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks) к `GetThumbnailImage` читали? Он может выдавать очень плохое качество при размерах больше 120. Может, в этом и причина.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код выглядит абсолютно валидным. Возможные варианты:

1. Проверьте `originalPicPath` возможно что-то не так с путем к файлу.
2. Можно попробовать явно указать расширение для сохраняемого файла.
3. У вас что-то с PS, проверял на лицензионной версии 2022, мне не удалось воспроизвести ту же ошибку. Возможно, это подтверждает первую версию, если указывать другое расширение для изображение PS все равно разбирает его кодировку и открывает штатно, но это только в новых версиях. В старых, насколько я помню, была такая ошибка при несоответствии кодировки изображения и расширения.

Также лучше не использовать `System.Drawing` это решение не является кроссплатформенным и качество обработки изображений не лучшее.

Comment: Что значит "качестао обработки изображений" плохое? Не вводите в заблуждение. Если взялись оценивать библиотеку, добавьте конструктива. Если утверждаете, что она плохая и не кросс-платформенная, предложите хорошию и кросс-платформенную. Это может оаазаться полезным. Как по мне, так эта библиотека с рисованием прекрасно справляется. А если вам фотки ретушировать надо и фильтры накладывать, так [программируйте их сами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228842/373567).